# How can I blend images taken at different times of the day into the same panorama?

Tags: astrophotography, landscape, panorama, milky-way

Is there a way to take a same set of images for a panorama twice at different times of the day? I would like to blend these images using a layer mask in Photoshop so I get a blue hour foreground and milky way shot of the night.

For example for a milky way shoot I would shoot the blue hour for the background and of course at the night for milky.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes i would like to blend those images using a layer mak in PS

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to take a same set of images for a panaroma twice

Yes. Simply do it a second time.

You can be more consistent by using reference markings.

For the tripod, that could be the join of tiles on the floor for example, a natural landmark like big stone that your tripod legs are touching, etc.

You could also try marking the position the legs of the tripod with sticks, but other visitors of the location, animals or wind could move those around.

Another solution to finding the tripod p position again would be to never move it. On a public location, this means staying with your gear until the conditions for the second image are there, which may or may not be possible.
In other situations, like the view from the terrace of the house you rented for vacation or private property, this could be a viable solution.

Keep your tripod head mounted on the tripod between both shots. Do not modify the head orientation. Mark the positions of each shot on the panorama scale.

Remember or lock the focal length of using a zoom lens.

Remember that you won't achieve pixel perfect alignment of both images. But you don't need to either. Photoshop allows you to align two images.